# What is the Big-O runtime of buildHeap?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am having problems trying to find the Big-O runtime of this. It's building a heap by calling the insert function to insert the elements into the heap.

```
buildHeap(A)
 h = new empty heap
for each element e in A
h.insert(e)
```

What is the Big-O runtime of this version of buildHeap?

Comment: Inserting in heap is usually O(log n)

Comment: why is it O(log n)?

Comment: Most implementations of build_heap pretty much do exactly what you wrote above, with very slight optimizations.

Comment: @alwaysdiscrete Read the wikipedia page. It explains it.

Comment: @FrankYellin: That’s not true of practical implementations. The point of any dedicated function to build a heap from a list should be to use an O(n) heapify.

Comment: An item is added to a heap by putting it at the end of the array.  It is then repeatedly compared with its parent (the item at  (index - 1)//2) and swapping with its parent for as long as it is smaller than its parent.   This can happen at most log n times, where n is the length of an array.  

This should be described in any textbook on heaps.

Comment: Okay.  I'm finding a reference that says I'm wrong.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/. Because most elements are leaves, although the worst case time for any one call to heapify is O(log n), the amortized time is O(n) overall.  I learned something new.

Comment: Hint: Think about how many insertions are on the last full level compared to the total size, and think about whether you can make all of them the worst case insertion time.

Answer (score 0):

Written this way, for a typical binary heap, it would be `O(n log n)`; you're inserting one at a time, and each insertion is `O(log n)`. There are optimized ways to build a heap an array of elements all at once from `n` elements in `O(n)` time (referred to as the "heapify" operation), but it's not done by repeated single-element insertions.

The big-O could change depending on the type of heap; [some variant heap designs have `O(1)` insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants), though of course the come with other trade-offs that differ by type, e.g. memory fragmentation, complexity of implementation, higher fixed costs per operation, etc.

Comment: Each insertion is O(log n) on the heap’s current size, so this isn’t quite a complete way to show that O(n log n) is minimal.